# Grid cell value not found in javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, grid

I am not getting the grid cell value.It's always empty. How can i get the cellvalue?

Code:

```
function VallidRcvQuantity (txtcurrentrcved) {
     var grid = document.getElementById("<%=gvGoodReceived.ClientID%>");
     var txtcurrentrcvamount = txtcurrentrcved;

     for (var i = 0; i < grid.rows.length - 1; i++) {
          var cellValue = $("#gvGoodReceived").find("tr:eq(" + i + ")").find("td:eq(2)").text();

          if (Number(txtcurrentrcvamount) > Number(cellValue)) {
              alert("Receive quantity must be less or equal PO quantity");

              return false;
          }
      }

      return true;
  }
```

Comment: Why is this tagged as `c#`? Please either add what part is c# or remove the tag. (Unless that `<%=gvGoodReceived.ClientID%>` is somehow c#)

Comment: I recommend you use `parseInt` or `parseFloat` instead of `Number()`, as they are designed for converting strings to numbers.

Comment: Can you also please supply the grid.

Comment: I think you should use `var cellValue = parseInt(grid.rows[i].cells[n].childNodes[0].value);`, where n belongs to cell index.

Comment: Your code is correct and I have highlighted an important point that you are missing in my answer.

Comment: not working @TetsuyaYamamoto

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are not getting a cell value is because for the row with index 0, there are no `td` elements but only `th` elements within a `tr` element. This row is the header row.

So, you must either skip the first row in your original code or use code like below.

```
function getGridViewCellValue() {
    var grid = document.getElementById("<%=gvGoodReceived.ClientID%>");

    for (var i = 0; i < grid.rows.length - 1; i++) {
        var cell = $("#<%=gvGoodReceived.ClientID%>").find("tr:eq(" + i + ")").find("td:eq(2)");
        if (cell.length > 0) {
            var cellValue = cell.text();
            return cellValue;
        }

    }
 return null;//means no cell value was found
}
```

Comment: Change your code so that cellValue = $("#<%=gvGoodReceivedClientID%>")

Comment: The code I have in my answer works as   I have tested it on my side before posting it.

Comment: Please mark it as answer if it has solved your problem.